# Infinispan search indexing error: LockedObtainFailedException

Tags: java, lucene, infinispan

I'm new to Infinispan and I am currently trying to use the search functionality.  I have tried following closely with the documentation.  First I update my cache.xml:

```
<namedCache 
       name="cache">
       <transaction transactionMode="NON_TRANSACTIONAL"/>
           <indexing enabled="true" indexLocalOnly="true"/>
</namedCache>
```

I am trying to write a query that will give me a list of results of the attribute of the search_value.  Here is the Java code that I have:

```
SearchManager searchManager = org.infinispan.query.Search.getSearchManager(cache);
Term t = new Term("attribute_name", search_value);
Query q  = new TermQuery(t);
CacheQuery cacheQuery = searchManager.getQuery(q);
List<Object> found = cacheQuery.list();
```

However, when I try to run the tests, I am getting this error:

```
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@.\Key\write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:84)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1098)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.applyUpdates(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.run(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
13/08/02 14:08:25 ERROR lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask: HSEARCH000072: Couldn't open the IndexWriter because of previous error: operation skipped, index ouf of sync!
```

What is causing the writelock error?  I have even tried to remove the Java part with just the index configuration and the same error exists.  Am I not configuring the cache correctly?  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Weird, what Infinispan version? Do you see any other errors in the log? What tests are you executing precisely?

Comment: I'm currently using Infinispan 6.0.  The test I'm currently running inserts 1000 entries into the cache and performs a range search on the key attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying search engine, based on Hibernate Search and Apache Lucene, uses locks to request exclusive write access to the index.
Assuming you don't have a second application attempting to write on the same index directory, you likely have a left-over lock file in the directory from a killed JVM or hardware crash.

Look for a directory being created on the filesystem having the same name as the index (indexes) you're using and remove the marker file *write.lock* (if you're sure that no process is writing it).

You could also configure a different locking strategy, but make sure you won't shoot yourself:
 [LockFactory configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-configuration-directory-lockfactories)

If this is not a left-over lock from a previously killed JVM, then it could be that you're running multiple Infinispan instances. Make sure they store the indexes in separate base directories (the default is the current path you're starting the process from).

[Directory configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-configuration-directory)